# Call python script from express

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

I am trying to run a python script with `child_process`, I am testing with a simple script that prints `hello` but the output I am getting back is `undefinedhello`

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print ('hello')
```

app.js

```
router.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const py = spawn('/usr/bin/python3', ['./python/script.py']);
    
    let output;
    py.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
          output += data;
    });
    py.stdout.on("close", () => {
        console.log(output);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

I have tried several suggestions but none have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;     // this should be out of the router

router.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    
    const py = spawn('/usr/bin/python3', ['./python/script.py']);
    
    let output;
    py.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
          output += data.toString();
    });
    py.on("close", () => {                     // this differs 
        console.log(output);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

Reference [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_spawn)

Comment: Just to add I need to do `let output = "";` to remove `undefined`.